# Can a Haskell/GHC self-report its GC stats live?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm thinking that having a server to self-report its memory usage would be handy.

I have read the section on [memory profiling](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.1/docs/html/users_guide/prof-heap.html) in the manual, but there are a few drawbacks with this:

- First this seems to give only post-mortem stats.
- There is an overhead associated with enabling profiling.
- I don't really need that much detail.

So that's my question, how can one track the different sets of memory in a running program compiled by GHC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The GHC-specific module `GHC.Stats` provides a function [`getGCStats`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/GHC-Stats.html#v:getGCStats) whichs returns (in `IO`) various GC statistics:

> ```
> getGCStats :: IO GCStats
> ```
>
> Retrieves garbage collection and memory statistics as of the last
>   garbage collection. If you would like your statistics as recent as
>   possible, first run a `performGC`.

Answer (score 10):

If you integrate [ekg](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ekg) into your server, you can access nice graphs and statistics about the runtime and even your own custom metrics via HTTP:

[image]

(Image linked from [Oliver Charles’ blogpost on ekg](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2012-12-11-24-day-of-hackage-ekg.html))

Comment: That's definitely something I want to do! Thanks.